# Need help ignoring button press. Tkinter

Tags: python

I am working on making a stopwatch program. I can't get the start button to do nothing if the timer is already running.

When I search, I see the same [14 year old code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/124894-stopwatch-in-tkinter/). I'd find it hard to believe that all these individuals in the past 14 years have independently arrived at the same solution.

As a beginner, I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong with what I've written instead of copy/pasting and moving on.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import datetime


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title('Stopwatch')

        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        quit_button = Button(self, text = 'Quit', command = self.client_exit)
        quit_button.config(width = 9)
        quit_button.place(x=230)

        start_button = Button(self, text = 'Start', command = self.timer_start)
        start_button.config(width= 10)
        start_button.place(x=0, y=0)

        stop_button = Button(self, text = 'Stop', command = self.timer_stop)
        stop_button.config(width = 10)
        stop_button.place(x=80)

        reset_button = Button(self, text = 'Reset', command = self.timer_reset)
        reset_button.config(width = 10)
        reset_button.place(x=160)

        self.is_timer_running = False

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def timer_start(self):
        global sec1
        sec1 = time.time()
        if self.is_timer_running == False:
            self.is_timer_running = True
            def tick():
                if self.is_timer_running == True:
                    sec = time.time()
                    sec = datetime.timedelta(seconds = sec - sec1)
                    clock['text'] = sec
                    clock.after(100, tick)
            tick()

    def timer_stop(self):
        stop_time = time.time()
        if self.is_timer_running == True:
            self.is_timer_running = False
            def tick_stop():
                stop = datetime.timedelta(seconds = stop_time - sec1)
                clock['text'] = stop
            tick_stop()

    def timer_reset(self):
        self.is_timer_running = False
        clock['text'] = '00:00:00'
```

Comment: So you want to disable the buttons temporally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the state of the button to disabled immediately after it's clicked (make sure to update it), and then set it back to normal when the timer stops running.

```
start_button.config(state = 'disabled')
start_button.update()

# do whatever you need to do i.e run the stop watch

start_button.update()
start_button.config(state = 'normal')
```

And thanks to @NickBonne for further clarification :)

> You need to add `self.start_button = start_button` and `self.stop_button = stop_button` in `init_window()`. Then you can use `self.start_button.config(state="disabled")`

Comment: Ah foo! You beat me by just a few seconds ;)

Comment: `state="enabled"` is invalid, allowed states are `"active"`, `"normal"`, and `"disabled"`

Comment: I think `"active"` isn't really wanted in this application, IIRC it simulates pressing the button which in this case would start the stopwatch again immediately.

Comment: @Harrison
If I add your solution to my start and stop button command functions, it results in name error. "start_button not defined."

Unless your solution is added to the init_window function, the name error persists.

Comment: @Dartmouth: setting the state wouldn't simulate pressing the button and starting the watch again. All the state does is change some color and border options. It doesn't simulate a click.

Comment: @NickBonne You need to add `self.start_button = start_button` and `self.stop_button = stop_button` in `init_window()`. Then you can use `self.start_button.config(state="disabled")`